# Change language of command in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, language

How can you change the language of the commands in Excel to English? Now the language of the commands are in Dutch (equal to the language of my pc). But can you change it into English? I use Windows 10 and Office 2013.

For example: This command

```
=ALS(SOM(B1:B8)>5; VANDAAG(); REST(20;11))
```

is in dutch but the same command is this

```
=IF(SUM(B1:B8)>5; TODAY(); REST(20;11))
```

in English.

Comment: Thank you for your question, +1, I had the same problem! See my comment under the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your Office version. With an Office 365 license that has received Office 2016 you can change the language.

Go File > Options > Language and click on "How do I get more Display and Help Languages".

You may need to download some files to do that. The "how to" link gets you to  [this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Language-Accessory-Pack-for-Office-2016-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US&fromAR=1).

With older versions of Office you may need to install the localised language version, and that may not be a free download.

Comment: This was very useful to me, +1! It is absurd that one should change the language of all the Office package only to have the Excel formulas in  English, but it's Microsoft, no surprise!

Comment: Is there a way to only have the formulas in English, but have the UI in a different language?