# Change excel formula language using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, language

I need to be able to use english formula on my french laptop. Is it possible to use this without installing a language pack?

I have seen this answer from Microsoft:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mobile-mso_2013_release/change-excel-formula-language/d6bf1b1a-5df0-4140-93c0-f2632c65aaa0

or here [Change language of command in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/984789/change-language-of-command-in-excel)

but I thought maybe a VBA solution was possible. Any ideas or tips about where to search?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change language of command in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/984789/change-language-of-command-in-excel)

Comment: No, even with vba you can't change it without changing the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you already did some research, but don't want to give up hope...however, there isn't much. This issue alone is enough of a nuisance to mandate only English installations of Excel for me. Personally, I don't see why there shoudn't be an option for international installations to use English in formulas instead of the interface language, but that's how it is.

Unfortunately, you cannot **change** the language for formulas through a VBA script.

You could use VBA to **assign** English formulas to cells, but they would then appear translated to the interface language:

```
Sub add_formula()
  Range("A1").Value = "=SUM(B:B)"
End Sub
```

[image]

See this well-written [post](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/writing-formulas-with-macros/) for a couple of useful hints on the subject.

What I do and my recommendation is to only use very simple formulas, which you can quickly and easily translate using this [table](https://dolf.trieschnigg.nl/excel/index.php). for anything more, use VBA code, which is portable across language installations.