# How can I change Excel so that I can enter English rather than German formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, language, i18n

I want to change my Excel installation such that I can enter formulas in English rather than in German. I believe, I should be able to change the corresponding settings under *File -> Options -> Languages*  (German: *Daten -> Optionen -> sprache*). However, I am not able to change anything to English (such as the Menu entries etc.)

When I choose this option, I am presented with the following GUI:

[image]

Bearbeitungspsrache (which translates to something like *editing language*) is set to *English (United States) Standard Setting* (again my translation). So, I guess this should be sufficient to enter english formulas, but I seem to be wrong on that.

Furthermore, the *Anzeigesprache* and *Hilfesprache* (display language and help language) are set to *adjust to Microsoft Windows* and *adjust to display language*. The Windows language, as far as I can tell, *is* english also, under the *Language Settings*, I find:

[image]

As far as I can tell, I have an Office 2016. In VBA, `application.version` returns `16.0`.

So, what do I have to change to enter formulas in English?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change language of command in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/984789/change-language-of-command-in-excel)

Comment: Btw, which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: It is disappointing not to see any responses on the answers, neither acceptance nor comments (or dv's) on wrong answers.

Comment: @Rene Have you found a solution? I do have the same issue on my computer, and would love to hear how you were able to solve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Frist you should be sure to have installed the English version Of Office. Then In the "File"-> "Option" -> "Language" location, to set English as default. （Set both in "Choose Editing Language" box and "Choose Display Language" box)

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. Office comes in multiple language versions and the formula/VBA language is hardcoded to the installed language version of the software. Regional settings and display/spellchecker-language of the application have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Tonny and Bella too. Only the first sentence is correct: *...installed the English version...*, the rest is not. A possible exception is Office365, which `teylyn` says has the ability to select formula language in its setup. And Bella, I want to emphasize that the question is about the language when you enter formulae.

Comment: I am not sure what I am to make of this answer and its 2nd comment. How do I know if I have an English version of Office? (Probably I don't because the Menu items are German). However, in *Choose Editing Language*, the *Editing Language* **is** set to English and in *Choose Display Language* I can only choose from *Match Microsoft Windows* and *German* (see my screen shot in the question). Also, my Windows installation appears to be english.

Comment: Well, actually after changing the language of MENU's in WORD, it changes the language of formulas in excel. Very annoying feature, you should be able to set the language for formulas separately in excel.